# How to shorten frequently used code in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

A C# engineering once showed me that you can shorten commands instead of constantly retyping them and now that I'm coding some automation, I was wondering how you go about this?

For example, I assigned `IWebDriver` to `driver` like so:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And now when I need to find and click things on a web page, each time I have to code the following:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath**("//input[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_SearchTextBox']")).SendKeys(templateID);
driver.FindElement(By.Id**("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_SearchButton")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id**("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_rptCampaignTemplates_ctl00_gi_lnkGalleryRequest")).Click();
```

How can I go about shortening the `driver.FindElement(By.Id` to something more easily typed like this:

```
actionId("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_SearchButton")).Click();
```

Comment: Are you looking for Code Snippets?  Here is how you do them in Visual Studio:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx    Or if you want something to happen in ANY textbox, you can search for "text expansion" to find some apps that will do what you want.

Comment: Define a string constant or three.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Code is not quoted text. Code is code.

Comment: Don't strive for easy typing.  Strive for maintainability.  Whatever method you use, you're effectively "aliasing-out" the primary API used for whatever it is you're doing at the moment, just to save a few keystrokes.  This does not make for more understandable code, either for maintainers who have to read what you wrote, or for yourself in a few months when you have to come back to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare your own extension method (see: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)) for the IWebDriver type:

```
public IWebElement ActionId(this IWebDriver driver, string id)
{
      return driver.FindElement(By.Id(id))
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
const string searchButtonId = "ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_Main_SearchButton";
driver.ActionId(searchButtonId).Click();
```

I personally would prefer a more descriptive name like "FindElementById"  instead of "ActionId".